# Is there a way to make multi-colored titles in Altair?

Tags: python, charts, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to make a multi-colored Altair chart title. I have a grouped bar chart with two columns (e.g. A and B) in different colors (e.g. red and blue), and I wanted the title to be something like "**A** and **B**" where A is written in the same color as its column and B as well.

While looking at documentation, I could only find how to change the color of the whole title, while I was looking for a more Latex-like approach. Is there any way to do this?